# How to config PHP/Apache such that 'Off', 'No', 'False', '0' return the same value?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration-files, ini

The display value of [`ini_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) for [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) flag is `""` (empty string) if the boolean is declared using the constants `Off`, `No`, or `False`.

However, if the boolean is declared using `0`, the display value is `"0"`.

Is there any PHP/Apache configuration which we can modify to change this behavior, such that we get the **same value** regardless of the way the boolean is declared?

Comment: I am afraid that this is the expected behavior for `ini_get`.  However why not test with your own function that place all the options `Off` `On` `false` `0` in one category? Something similar to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php#93014

Comment: @AntoanMilkov, Seems to be avoiding the question though. That still needs to be loaded before the call to `ini_get`. It's better to have this set up in the configuration where `ini_get` can be called anywhere anytime with this "consistent" behavior.

Comment: Well ... is it an option to make first a call to `ini_set` where you suspect that `ini_get` might be used? I guess this wont be an option. If this is the case then the only instruments that left are those that redefine the behavior of the native functions like: http://no2.php.net/runkit_function_redefine and http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Comment: @AntoanMilkov, Those code still need to be run before we use `ini_get`.

Comment: Don't you have access to the php code? How this code is deployed on the servers? I have interesting idea instead of configuring PHP/Apache to configure Git post-commit hook... This will work only in case when Git is used. However it can be fully automated and will work in any PHP enviroment.

Comment: @AntoanMilkov, Yes I have access to the php code but editing them all is not an option. Seems like the best option now I have is to use "override" together with auto prepend in .htacess unless there's a better solution. What do you mean by Git post-commit hook?

Comment: Are you using Git to deploy the code to the server(s) ?

Comment: @AntoanMilkov, I'm not using Git to deploy code to the server.